Semi-opaque background for text block in Elementor
I am editing my WordPress microsite using Elementor.
I have a big hero banner image over which I want to lay some text - a header and a text "editor" box. The text and image clash, so I want to put a darker background behind the box. I don't find any setting to do that.
See text 'Leading workforce development...'
The bottom is what I want*. The top is all I can manage:


I managed to make this semi-opaque background by using the Smart Slider plugin. That's overkill, but it also raises other design/usability problems, so it's not a desirable option.


You should be able to achieve this by using the second control in the color picker to set the opacity, just move it to the left and find the right result for you.

